# AngularJS: Bind attribute value from controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My markup was:

```
<input char-limit="10" />
```

Then I needed to set the attribute value from controller, so I did this:

```
 <input char-limit="{{charLimit}}" />
```

And in controller:

```
$scope.charLimit = <my value>;
```

Now, instead of using the model value directly; I need to use the function to return the value. So I did:

```
<input char-limit="getCharLimit()" />
```

And in controller:

```
$scope.getCharLimit= function(){
    return <my value>;
}
```

But the value is not reflected in the markup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enclose the function inside of curly braces

```
<input char-limit="{{getCharLimit()}}" />
```

Comment: Oops, what a dumb mistake! Thanks, will accept the answer after 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Typically an Angular Expression must be enclosed within {{ }}

```
{{ expression }}
```

So the correct one should be  : `<input char-limit="{{getCharLimit()}}" />`